# Spring Boot MVC with angular app static content behavior?

Tags: css, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am not sure what is happening with that behavior but when :
i include the following script link in the HTML

```
<link href='./css/style.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
```

the page is not applying css or js if I just open the HTML page in any browser directly, but it runs on the server and apply the links

when i include the following instead of the pervious link

```
<link href='../static/css/style.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/app.js"></script>
```

it Runs when open the Page in browser directly , but it is not applying when run on server
i can not figure out why this happening

Comment: Because you shouldn't use relative links... Use absolute links instead.

Comment: how should the absolute link be here in spring boot project and will it be ok with deployment ?

Comment: And why should it differ if you deploy or not?

Comment: what should be the relative link here for example ?

Comment: You already have relative links... Use absolute ones...

Comment: sorry i mean absolute

Comment: Also why are you opening it directly anyway? You should let spring boot serve it.. Opening it directly changes things, uses a different protocol etc.

Comment: can you give me a code example ?

Comment: An absolute one starts with `/`. `/static/js/app.js`.. But as stated you shouldn't be opening it directly in the first place...

Comment: the path did not work on server or even on the direct browser page

Comment: Sigh. I give up, it was a sample, the actual path depends on how/where your application is deployed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is because when you run on the server, Spring boot maps the `src/main/resources/static` folder to your context root (usually `/`).

That means that if you have the following structure:

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
      static/
        myStyle.css
      templates/
        index.html
```

Both the `src/main/resources/static/myStyle.css` and the `src/main/resources/templates/index.html` will be available as `/myStyle.css` and `/index.html`.

If you're using Spring boot you should **never** include the `static/` (or `templates/`) part in your links/references. You should **never** open the HTML page directly in your browser since this does not reflect any real environment.

To make it work locally you should run the Spring boot application and open the application through your browser, not just some HTML file in the project itself.